# LINQ to XML return an object instead of IEnumerable<object>

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have this code:

```
   MyObject Obj {get;set;}
    var x = from xml in xmlDocument.Descendants("Master")
        select new MyObject
        {
            PropOne = //code to get data from xml
            PropTwo = //code to get data from xml
        }
```

The result is `var` being `IEnumerable<MyObject>`, and I need to use a `foreach` loop to assign `x` to `Obj`:

```
foreach(var i in x)
{
    Obj = i;
}
```

Is there a way I can use a LINQ statement and not have an `IEnumerable` returned in that way? Or is it normal to use a `foreach` loop the way I am?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep:

```
Obj = (from xml in xmlDocument.Descendants("Master")
        select new MyObject
        {
            PropOne = //code to get data from xml
            PropTwo = //code to get data from xml
        }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're only returning one object, you can do this:

```
 MyObject Obj {get;set;}

 var x = (from xml in xmlDocument.Descendants("Master")
    select new MyObject
    {
        PropOne = //code to get data from xml
        PropTwo = //code to get data from xml
    }).Single();
```

Now your `x` object should be of type MyObject

Answer (score 1):

You need to retrieve the first item.  I would personally create this after your LINQ query:

```
var element = xmlDocument.Descendants("Master").Single(); // Or .First() if appropriate
Obj = new MyObject
    {
        PropOne = //code to get data from xml in "element"
        PropTwo = //code to get data from xml in "element"
    };
```

I personally find this more clearly matches your intent, as you're retrieving the single element, then building a single object from it.